Why Nginx prefers default_server instead of server block with exact host match
Check this nginx config. If sending a request like -
curl -H "Host: test.com" http://127.0.0.1:8200
Why does nginx use the second server block instead of the first block (with exact host and protocol match) and results in 400 error saying that plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port.
  server {
    listen 8200;
    server_name test.com;

    location / {
      return 200 'Block1';
    }
  }

  server {
    listen 8200 ssl default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/server.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/server.key;

    location / {
      return 200 'Block2';
    }
  }


You cannot run ssl and non-ssl on the same port. For any given port, ssl is either on of off.

@RichardSmith+ since 2018 you can -- but not the way OP tried

@dave_thompson_085 also one can have different settings on different interfaces, but it requires some fine tuning.

In this case flag ssl works for all servers that listen to port 8200. So both of yours server blocks expect https on port 8200.
Since you've sent plain http request to https port, nginx has no idea what host name you've send and request ends up in default server.

Should nginx at config validation?

Woud love to understand what exactly happens internally in this case.

@Parzival Internally nginx opens only one socket for port, and all server blocks that listen to that port share config.
